# How to read Ionic Webview version in Javascript?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-webview

Is there any way to read the webview version using JS in Ionic during runtime ?

I want to execute some code blocks based on the WKWebview version in iOS .

```
if (webview version is > 3.x) {

} else { 
// older webview versions.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.platform.userAgent()`, where platform is an instance of `import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';`, this should return a string containing the browser details of the environment you are running in.

For example my local browser running the app via `ionic serve` returned - `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36`.

You should be able to parse this string to find the relevant details you're after when the app is running in WKWebview.

Comment: userAgent() function does not exist on Ionic 4. I found cordova-plugin-webview-checker this plugin, might be useful